# Making decimal.Decimal the default numerical type in Python

Tags: python, decimal, interpreter, bc, dc

Is there some way I could make decimal.Decimal the default type for all numerical values in Python? I would like to be able to use Python in a manner similar to the bc and dc programs without having to call decimal.Decimal(...) for every number.

EDIT: For the uninitiated: [bc](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Bc_programming_language).

EDIT 2: Thank you [tokenize module.](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.untokenize).

Comment: Are you talking about ensuring the python does floating point arithmetic instead of integer arithmetic?

Comment: Perhaps you could hack the interpreter to do this, with a lot of effort. But why? When you write a Python program that needs decimal in some place, just use it there - way easier. If you need abritary precision decimals, use something that provides it. (And @seggy: float != decimal !!)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I posted.  You're right, there doesn't seem to be a way that doesn't involve some serious mucking with python internals.  Way more effort than the payoff would be worth, IMO.

Comment: I will probably end up using the module that allows you to make your own interpreter. See [code module.](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html)

Comment: Where does the "numerical input" comes from in your program? It would probably be easier to force a conversion there rather than making your own interpreter...

Comment: The numerical input comes from me. I want to be able to use Python like bc and dc which are arbitrary precision calculators that support a scripting language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the bottom of the tokenize module's documentation, there is a function that does exactly what I need:

- Python 3: "[Example of a script rewriter that transforms float literals into Decimal objects](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tokenize.html#examples)"
- Python 2: "[Example of a script re-writer that transforms float literals into Decimal objects](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.TokenError)"

Answer (score 6):

You cannot really do what you ask without some serious magic, which I won't try to touch upon in my answer, but there is at least a slightly easier way than doing `decimal.Decimal(...)`

```
from decimal import Decimal as D
num = D("1") + D("2.3")
```

Edit: use the shorter form from the comment.

Comment: Well yes, I _could_ do it that way, but I was looking for something that didn't require explicit action for every number.

Comment: Also, It'd be more like `D("2.3")` so I don't lose precision.

Comment: The problem is that Python is a generic programming language, and is notable for not wanting magic stuff to happen. As the python saying goes: "Explicit is better than implicit." Which is why any answer you get to this question that does exactly what you want will be hackish.